# Android Date Picker will not send data to a new Activity

Tags: android-activity, datepicker

I am using Androids Date Picker to select a date.  Once the user presses the button, the data should send to the next activity.  I verified that when the button is pressed, the correct date shows in the Date Picker file but the data that I want to go to the next Activity is showing null.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
int day;
int month;
int year;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnNextScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dateAccept);
    final DatePicker date = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

    //Listening to button event
    btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Starting a new Intent
            Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondscreen.class);
            Intent process = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),processing.class);

            day =date.getDayOfMonth();
            month =date.getMonth()+1;
            year=date.getYear();

            process.putExtra("Day", day);
            process.putExtra("Month", month);
            process.putExtra("Year", year);






            //Sending data to another Activity
            startActivity(process);
            startActivity(nextScreen);
        }



    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

The Processing class I have is

```
public class processing extends MainActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.third_screen);


    //TextView txthour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hours);
   // TextView txtmin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.min);

    TimePicker workStart= (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timetobeatwork);
    int workhour= workStart.getCurrentHour();
    int workmin= workStart.getCurrentMinute();

    System.out.println(workhour);
    System.out.println(workmin);




    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Receiving the Data

    final String hour = i.getStringExtra("Hour");
    final String minute = i.getStringExtra("Min");
    final String day = i.getStringExtra("Day");
    final String month = i.getStringExtra("Month");
    final String year = i.getStringExtra("Year");



    // Displaying Received data
    System.out.println("hour "+hour);
    System.out.println("min "+minute);
    System.out.println("day "+day);
    System.out.println("month "+month);
    System.out.println("year "+year);
}
```

The output I get is

```
07-16 08:22:41.486    2664-2664/com.erikkniaz.myapp.myapplication I/System.out﹕ min 8
07-16 08:22:41.486    2664-2664/com.erikkniaz.myapp.myapplication I/System.out﹕ hour 22
07-16 08:22:41.486    2664-2664/com.erikkniaz.myapp.myapplication I/System.out﹕ day null
07-16 08:22:41.486    2664-2664/com.erikkniaz.myapp.myapplication I/System.out﹕ month null
07-16 08:22:41.491    2664-2664/com.erikkniaz.myapp.myapplication I/System.out﹕ year null
```

Comment: i figured it out.  You have to pass the data through all the screens in order.  I was trying to send the data from screen 1 to screen 3.  Have to do screen 1 -> screen 2-> screen 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out. You have to pass the data through all the screens in order. I was trying to send the data from screen 1 to screen 3. Have to do screen 1 -> screen 2-> screen 3